# Question about lim inf and lim sup

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at the proof of a property of lim inf: Given a sequence of real numbers, there is a subsequence that converges to the lim inf. For the case when the lim inf is finite, the proof in the textbook goes as follows:

There is $j_1\geq 1$ such that $\vert A_1−a_{j_1}\vert<2^{−1}$. We choose $j_1$ to be as small as possible. Next, we choose $j_2$, necessarily greater than $j_1$, such that $j_2$ is as small as possible and $\vert A_2−a_{j_2}\vert<2^{−2}$. Continuing in this fashion, we select $j_k > j_{k−1}$ such that $\vert A_k−a_{j_k}\vert<2^{−k}$, etc.

Here $A_n=\inf\{a_k: k \geq n\}$. Now the rest of the proof is not very difficult to understand, but the one detail I'm stuck on is the "...$j_2$, necessarily greater than $j_1$..." part. Why is this true? Why can we always choose a $j_{k}>j_{k-1}$? I've been thinking about this for a while now and still can't figure it out. I only know the definition of lim inf and nothing else about it. This is in fact the first property of lim inf the author proves after giving the definition, so I would appreciate it if someone can explain it using only the definition without referencing any other results. Thanks!

Comment: It just means you can pick subsequence elements down the line. Think of the sequence $\{1,-1,1,-1,...\}$. Here you can take $j_1 = 2, j_2=4,...$. The point is that if lim inf exists, you can always picks $a_{j_k}$ further down the line. Note that we index by $j_k$ instead of $k$ precisely because in this example, $j_k$ for lim inf happens to be the "even" elements (i.e. $j_k = 2k$). If you don't require $j_k>j_{k-1}$, you are essentially arranging your new sequence haphazardly and it's hard to perform the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A_1\leq A_2$. Now, if it is an equality $a_{j_1}$ was chosen so that $j_1$ is the minimal index. Thus if $|A_2-a_2|\leq 2^{-2}$, $|A_1-a_2|\leq 2^{-2}<1/2$ which forces $a_{j_1}<a_{j_2}$.

If $<$ then $A_1=a_1$. Its clear then that $a_{j_1}=a_1$. Thus $j_1<j_2$.

Now suppose we have $\{a_{j_i}\}_{i=1}^{k-1}$ with $|A_i-a_{j_i}|<2^{-i}$ and $a_{j_{k-1}}$ has minimal index. Then we need to find an index with $|A_k-a_{j_k}|\leq 2^{-k}$.

If we have $A_k=A_{k-1}$ then a similar argument to the one above shows $a_{j_{k-1}}<a_{j_k}$. Otherwise $A_{k-1}=a_{k-1}$ and we have $a_{k-1}=a_{j_{k-1}}$ and so we are done.

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you!